# Oracle SQL - A count that excludes completely a Key with the if not equal statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Ok here goes:

MyTableName

```
KEY      Value1      
1        ABC         
1        DEF         
1        GHI 
2        ABC 
2        DEF 
2        YUI
```

I have a child table that is linked via a Key (stated above)

I need to find records, linked to the parent table (i have no issues with my join) where value 1 meets conditions and does not meet certain conditions.

So, for my Example, I want to retrieve the value '1' from the "KEY" above, because my need is where value 1 = 'ABC' or value 1 = 'DEF' but value 1 != YUI,

so I would want '1' to come back, but not 2

```
    SELECT KEY, count(*) 
    FROM MyTableName
    WHERE (value1 = 'ABC' 
    OR value1 = 'DEF')
    AND value1 != 'YUI'
    GROUP BY KEY
    HAVING count(KEY) = 2
```

The above statement, find both Key 1 and 2, where I need it only to find Key 1.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `HAVING` clause with conditional counts:

```
select key
from mytablename
group by key
having count(case when value1 in ('ABC','DEF') then 1 end) > 0 
   and count(case when value1 = 'YUI' then 1 end) = 0;
```

(You can add `where value1 in ('ABC','DEF','YUI')`, which may speed up the query, because you are not interested in rows containing other values.)

(Some people prefer to include an explicit `else` branch: `count(case when value1 = 'YUI' then 1 else null end)` and others prefer `sum(case when value1 = 'YUI' then 1 else 0 end)`. That's a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: ok - tried this, and it sort of half worked... I had to 

select key from mytablename
group by key
having count(case when value1 in ('ABC') then 1 end) > 0 
    and count(case when value1 in ('DEF') then 1 end) > 0 
    count(case when value1 = 'YUI' then 1 end) = 0;

I had to split it out on each line... otherwise, as soon as either ABC or DEF, it keeps it counted.  I need it to be ABC AND DEF are found within the same key.

Comment: Okay, you said  ABC *or* DEF. You are right, for ABC *and* DEF you need two separate conditions.